# How to install and configure YII in shared server?

Tags: php, yii

I have successfully installed and configured YII in my Ubuntu machine using the yiic command line utility.

I have use this command.

```
YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp myapplication
```

But when I try to run the application in a shared server it is not getting the library files.

Comment: Install on local machine and upload from it.

Comment: If so I would not post it in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are working on Ubuntu i'm assuming your lampp is under /**opt** folder.

After executing your command ***YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp myapplication***, Folder structure will come as

```
   opt
    |
    |
    -- lampp
    |    |
    |    |
    |    --- htdocs
    |    |     |
    |    |     |
    |    |     ---------Yii
    |    |     |        
    |    |     ---------myapplication
```

Here, When you run the app "**myapplication**", the base class "**YiiBase**" will be called from **Yii** folder(Yii core) which is out side of your project.

When you are going to make your app live, Don't forget to upload both the folders ie, you need to upload both "Yii" and "myapplication" folders.

For better practice, Keep **Yii** folder inside the **myapplication** folder and change the index page. Usually index.php page comes like bellow,

```
        <?php

        // change the following paths if necessary
        $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php';
        $config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

        // remove the following lines when in production mode
        defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
        // specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
        defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

        require_once($yii);
        Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Change this line

```
       $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php';
```

to

```
       $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/yii/framework/yii.php';
```

Do this in your localhost and upload the same app to live. It will work without giving any troubles.